# building python package with parent folder in structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a python package that contains the following structure:

```
foo/
 __init__.py
 bar_module_one/
  __init__.py
  do_something_cool.py
 buzz_module_two/
  __init__.py
  youre_lazy.py
```

In `setup.py` I have the following:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup


setup(
    version="0.1.0",
    name="foo",
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_dir={"foo": "foo"},
)
```

I can't figure out how to make it so the package installs as the same structure. It currently just installs `bar_module_one/` and `buz_module_two/`, but I want the modules to be installed as part of foo. I want to be able to do `from foo.bar_module_one.do_something_cool import yo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make [setup.py listing the whole packages](https://docs.python.org/3.11/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages) by `package_dir={"": "foo"}` like this:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    version="0.1.0",
    name="foo",
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_dir={"": "foo"},
)
```

I'm not sure but you may have to change your project structure to add the `foo` directory as parent:

```
foo/
  foo/
    __init__.py
    bar_module_one/
      __init__.py
      do_something_cool.py
    buzz_module_two/
      __init__.py
      youre_lazy.py
  setup.py
```

Comment: yeah I already tried this too ! It makes the pathing a little funky